# startActivityForResult Android Paypal PaymentActivity is not giving me result back and and app closed without any error

Tags: java, android, paypal, paypal-sandbox, payment

[enter image description here][1]when I am calling startActivityForResult  Paypal PaymentActivity it does not give me any result back and my app closed without any error or exception

I was integrated GitHub source https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-Android-SDK/blob/master/docs/single_payment.md form the following link but when I changed my subscription Activity as main launcher activity in manifest it works but as a child activity, it does not work.

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Eig9F.png  Error Log

Comment: Please share your error logs also for better understanding.

Comment: I uploaded my Error log please check it out